# "Live Editor" in Python (Spyder)?

Tags: spyder, live

in MATLAB you can create interactive scripts via the Live Editor feature (*.mlx)

Is there something similar in Spyder? Any other Python IDE?

THANKS

Comment: There is Jupyter Notebook. You can use a simple version of it in Google Colab.

Comment: Thank you @Naetmul 
Do you happen to know if there is something similar in Spyder as well?